# How do I sum up all numbers in a line in csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

Basically I have a .csv file:

```
math,4,5,5,4,4,5
biology,3,4,4,2,3,2
chemistry,3,5,4,3,4,2
english,5,5,5,4,5,5
```

And in the end I need it to print the arithmetic mean of the subject:

```
math: 4.5
biology: 3.0
chemistry: 3.5
english: 4.8
```

I've tried some stuff and I got all of the numbers into a one list, but it doesn't help me much.

Edit: Added, what I have so far.

```
fail = open("grades.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")

info = []
a = []

for row in fail:
    parts = row.strip("\n").split(",")
    info.append(parts)

fail.close()

print(info)

for el in info:
    print(str(el[0]) + ":")
    for i in el[1:]:
        a.append(i)

print(a)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "got all of the numbers into a one list"? It sounds like you are nearly there. Please show the code you are using so far.

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in open('myfile.csv'):
    data = line.split(",")
    subject = data[0]
    grades = [float(x) for x in data[1:]]
    print(subject, sum(grades)/len(grades))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `csv` module to process csv data:

```
import csv

with open("grades.csv", encoding = "UTF-8") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        sub, *grades = row
        grades = list(map(float, grades))
        avg = sum(grades) / len(grades)
        print("{}: {}".format(sub, avg))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
dic = {}
for i in range(len(df)):
    subject = df.loc[i].tolist()[0]
    total = df.loc[i].tolist()[1:]
    dic[subject] = sum(total)/len(total)
```

You can use the `tolist()` method to separate the subject name and the marks. Then you can calculate the average.